# Proxy blocking file_get_contents

Tags: php, proxy, file-get-contents

In my business I have to use google map for my application (calculated distance)
We currently use a configuration script for proxy.
In my application I use the method to query `file_get_contents` Google Map.

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?language=fr&origin='.$adresse1.'&destination='.$adresse2.'&sensor=false';;

  $xml=file_get_contents($url);
  $root = simplexml_load_string($xml);
  $distance=$root->route->leg->distance->value;
  $duree=$root->route->leg->duration->value; 
  $etapes=$root->route->leg->step;
  return array(
     'distanceEnMetres'=>$distance,
     'dureeEnSecondes'=>$duree,
     'etapes'=>$etapes,
     'adresseDepart'=>$root->route->leg->start_address,
     'adresseArrivee'=>$root->route->leg->end_address
  );
}
```

But with the proxy I have an unknown host error. (I tested my home, the code works fine). I wanted to know if there is a way to take into account the proxy that I identify myself as when I browse the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). It's a bit more verbose than a simple call to `file_get_contents()`, but a lot more configurable:

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?language=fr&origin='.$adresse1.'&destination='.$adresse2.'&sensor=false';

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, ''); // your proxy address (and optional :port)
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, ''); // credentials in username:password format (if required)
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$xml = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

//continue logic using $xml as before
```

Answer (score 0):

the google have restrictions to number of queries per time segment for it's api

at first u must cache results on your side, and add a pause between queries

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can also mention a "context" to make file_get_contents recognize a proxy. Please see my own question and my own answer to that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648681/file-get-contents-fails-w-empty-exception/31671809#31671809)